# Datagrid Column with DropDown List To Be Shown on One Mouse Click

Tags: wpf, datagrid, behavior, dropdownbox

I have a WPF datagrid as shown in the code below. The Trade column of the grid has a dropdown. When a user clicks on the cell it selects the cell. They then have to click on the cell again, to be taken to the cell edit mode and show the dropdown. They then have to click on the cell a third time in order to see the dropdown's list.

I wanted to know if anyone can either show me how to dropdown the combo's list on the first click instead of 3 clicks or perhaps point me in the direction of what I should be looking to do in order to enable this. Thanks in advance.

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" Grid.Row="0" Name="grd_S_TML" CanUserAddRows="False" TabIndex="41" MinHeight="{Binding Grd_S_TMLHeight}" ItemsSource="{Binding GrdSTmlCollection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding GrdSTmlSelectedIndex}" SelectedItem="{Binding GrdSTmlSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                              behaviors:DragManagerExtended.DragOverCommand="{Binding GrdStmlDragOverCommand}" behaviors:DragManagerExtended.DragDropCommand="{Binding GrdStmlDragDropCommand}" behaviors:DragManagerExtended.IsDropTarget="True" ContextMenu="{StaticResource mnuMGridPopUp}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OverrideGridCellHighlight}" 
                                              behaviors:DragManagerExtended.IsNeedToBeDisposed="{Binding IsFormClosed}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding SequenceNo}" Width="0" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Width="0" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Trade" Width="201">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=TradeSelectedItem.Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cboTrades" ItemsSource="{Binding TradeCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding TradeSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <behaviors:KeyPressedBehavior>
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.RoleComboBoxKeyPressEvent}" />
                            </behaviors:KeyPressedBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pay Rate" Width="60">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PayRate, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCenterAlligned}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PayRate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="6" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty" Width="60">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCenterAlligned}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="6" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate (p/hr)" Binding="{Binding Path=RateHR, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" Width="60" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignDataGridTextColumnStyle}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value (£)" Binding="{Binding ItemValue, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" Width="60" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignDataGridTextColumnStyle}"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:DataGridColumnIndexAndCellPositionBehavior ColumnIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmOrderPricing},Path=StmlColumnIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <behaviors:DataGridRowClickBehavior RowClickCommand="{Binding GrdStmlMouseDownCommand}" />
        <behaviors:DataGridCellEditEndingBehavior CellEditEndingCommand="{Binding GrdStmlAfterColUpdateCommand}" />
        <behaviors:DataGridBeginningEditBehavior BeginningEditCommand="{Binding GrdStmlBeforeColEditCommand}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GrdStmlLostFocusCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <behaviors:KeyPressedBehavior>
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GrdStmlKeyPressCommand}" />
        </behaviors:KeyPressedBehavior>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GrdStmlRowColChangeCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="Edit"></Condition>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.LoadSalesOnly}" Value="false"></Condition>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ROW_STYLE_HIGHLIGHT_CHANGE}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="Add"></Condition>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.LoadSalesOnly}" Value="false"></Condition>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ROW_STYLE_HIGHLIGHT_NEW}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="Delete"></Condition>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.LoadSalesOnly}" Value="false"></Condition>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ROW_STYLE_HIGHLIGHT_DELETE}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowStatus}" Value="View">
                </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've solved this. Thought I'd post it here for others who might stumble upon this problem.

I created a behavior on the following dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAllowSingleClickEditProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAllowSingleClickEdit", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridCellSingleClickEditDependency), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsAllowSingleClickEditChanged));
```

...in the behavior I linked this event to this method...

```
private static void IsAllowSingleClickEditChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell dataGridCell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (dataGridCell != null)
        {
            if (e.NewValue.Equals(true))
            {
                dataGridCell.GotFocus += DataGridCellGotFocusHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridCell.GotFocus -= DataGridCellGotFocusHandler;
            }
        }
    }
```

... and then finally this code in the DataGridCellGotFocusHandler...

```
DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            if (!cell.IsFocused)
            {
                cell.Focus();
            }

            DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);

            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                dataGrid.BeginEdit(e);
                if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
                {
                    if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    {
                        cell.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                    if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                    {
                        row.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }

                Control control = GetFirstChildByType<Control>(e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell);
                if (control != null)
                {
                    control.Focus();

                    TextBox txt = control as TextBox;
                    if (txt != null)
                    {
                        txt.Select(0,txt.Text.Length);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rolling your own combo box in a `DataGridTemplate` column with a combobox.... It might be worthwhile to look into a [DataGridComboBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8)?

[image]